# How to unrealize a json using GSON? Get an error

Tags: android, json, gson

The structure of the json that I have stored in a string is:

```
{
"0": {
        "PDate": "2019-02-25 00:00:00.0000000",
        "DDate": "2019-06-25 00:00:00.0000000",
        "Document": "FC",
        "Direction": "CALLE ...."     
     },
"1": {
        "PDate": "2019-02-25 00:00:00.0000000",
        "DDate": "2019-06-25 00:00:00.0000000",
        "Document": "FC",
        "Direction": "CALLE ...."  
     }
}
```

I'm using the following code, but it shows an error in the last line:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()){
    Object object = response.body();
    String jsonString = String.valueOf(object);
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type empMapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Object>>() {}.getType();
    Map<Integer, Object> nameObjectJson = gson.fromJson(jsonString, empMapType);
}
```

The error message:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 29 path $..PostingDate
```

Please, I need help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First - create the POJO / Model class to convert your response.

```
public class SomeModel{

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name = null;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

Declare your response

```
 Gson gson = new Gson(); 
 SomeModelResponse response = gson.toJson(result, SomeModel.class);
```

If you will use Gson object more than one time - its better to create a singleton of it because every time when you create a new instance of it - it is use a lot of memory.

After add checking:

```
    if(response !=null && response.getName() !=null){

    if(response.getName().equalIgnoreCase("some name")){
              // show toast Result Success !!! and move to next screen
     }
    else if(response.getName().equalIgnoreCase("another name")){
     // Invalid Response !!! your logic here
    }
 }
```

Also don't forget to check what kind of response are you expect to get. It should not be an Object.class

Comment: Thanks for your answer, perhaps I did not explain well that the names of the nodes "1", "2" vary depending on the quantity which can increase or decrease. What I need is to convert the string to a model class, I know it's done as you tell me but in the same way it throws me an error. The string is the same json of the image
What would be the model class for this if the label of the nodes increase or decrease depending on the quantity? Thansk

Comment: I didn't see your JSON. Probably you added it after. 
Check @shb answer. He used the names from your Json model.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that error message include "$..PostingDate"
but I can NOT clarify the content of "response.body()", try this:

```
String jsonString = String.valueOf(object);
```

=>

```
String jsonString = object.toString();
```

And try to print out to see what it is.

Comment: Thank you very much. I resolved this problem using Scalars (com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars). To used Scalars all data is string and then formater this string and solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Create your DataModel

```
class Example {

    @SerializedName("PDate")
    @Expose
    private String pDate;
    @SerializedName("DDate")
    @Expose
    private String dDate;
    @SerializedName("Document")
    @Expose
    private String document;
    @SerializedName("Direction")
    @Expose
    private String direction;

    public String getPDate() {
        return pDate;
    }

    public void setPDate(String pDate) {
        this.pDate = pDate;
    }

    public String getDDate() {
        return dDate;
    }

    public void setDDate(String dDate) {
        this.dDate = dDate;
    }

    public String getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(String document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

}
```

---

Now parse it

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = "{\n" +
                "\"0\": {\n" +
                "        \"PDate\": \"2019-02-25 00:00:00.0000000\",\n" +
                "        \"DDate\": \"2019-06-25 00:00:00.0000000\",\n" +
                "        \"Document\": \"FC\",\n" +
                "        \"Direction\": \"CALLE ....\"     \n" +
                "     },\n" +
                "\"1\": {\n" +
                "        \"PDate\": \"2019-02-25 00:00:00.0000000\",\n" +
                "        \"DDate\": \"2019-06-25 00:00:00.0000000\",\n" +
                "        \"Document\": \"FC\",\n" +
                "        \"Direction\": \"CALLE ....\"  \n" +
                "     }\n" +
                "}";



 Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Example>>(){}.getType();
 Map<String, Example> myMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);

 //Log.d("===", myMap.get("0").document);
```

---